# Subscription API in recurly

Tags: php, recurly

I am trying to fetch subscription data using recurly.js api in PHP.Below is my code:

```
require_once('lib/recurly.php');
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'https://subdomain.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions';
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = 'privatekey';
$subscriptions = Recurly_SubscriptionList::getActive();
print_r($subscriptions);
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
   print_r($subscription);
}
```

$subscriptions is printing this:

```
Recurly_SubscriptionList Object(
  [_position:Recurly_Pager:private] => 0
  [_objects:protected] => 
  [_href:protected] => /subscriptions?state=active
  [_type:protected] => 
  [_client:protected] => Recurly_Client Object
    (
        [_apiKey:Recurly_Client:private] => 
        [_acceptLanguage:Recurly_Client:private] => en-US
    )

  [_links:protected] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

While $subscription is printing nothing.What went wrong that the result is not the list of the subscriptions.

Comment: Can you try and provide the output for print_r(gettype($subscriptions));

Comment: The output is only word object.

Comment: How about print_r(get_obj_vars($subsriptions));

Comment: No output just blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Since print_r(gettype($subscription)); is an object you cannot treat it as an array. In order to get the properties of an object as an array you can use an inbuilt function [get_obj_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

You may follow this code:

```
require_once('lib/recurly.php');
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'https://subdomain.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions';
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = 'privatekey';
$subscriptions = Recurly_SubscriptionList::getActive();
foreach(get_obj_vars($subscription) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value;
}
```

This would basically create an array of all public members in the object **$subscriptions**. But, as your output for print_r($subscriptions); contains only private and protected members, it would practically return you an empty array.

Comment: I referred to this documentation https://dev.recurly.com/docs/list-subscriptions. Why I am not able to produce the same output.

Comment: It is because you're following it wrong. Those docs are just an example. You need to replace __Recurly_Client::$subdomain = https://subdomain.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions';__ with an actual subdomain and __Recurly_Client::$apiKey = 'privatekey';__  with an actual private key. You receive them on registering, not passing random values.

Comment: Please upvote the answer, as it is the only solution to the issue you've asked.

Comment: I am passing the actual values I got on registering.Here I just replaced them with dummy text.

Comment: Which property do you wish to extract from the object?

Comment: subscription name and status.

Comment: Since there are no current subscriptions, it is returning null as an array, that's why you are facing an issue. Get a subscription, update the output.

Comment: I have two subscriptions with active status.

Answer (score 0):

The subscription array can be printed in a readable format by using the preformat tags as shown below.  Also, note a correction has been made in how your subdomain is entered in the code.

```html
<?php
require_once('lib/recurly.php');
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = '<mySubdomain>';  //Only enter the Recurly subdomain name here, not URL
Recurly_Client::$apiKey = 'privatekey';
$subscriptions = Recurly_SubscriptionList::getActive();
print_r($subscriptions);

foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    
    //print_r($subscription);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r (array($subscription));
    echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have written the whole URL of your subdomain which is causing the issue.
so just replace this line

```
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'https://subdomain.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions';
```

with

```
Recurly_Client::$subdomain = 'your-subdomain-name'; // i.e devapp,myapp..etc
```

You don't need to write whole subdomain URL you just need to pass your subdomain name which is found in configuration -> site setting (Only the name of the subdomain).

whatever name given to your subdomain at the time of signup.